# accessing sql in PHP with user and password

Tags: php, mysql

i have a small problem with my code
it allows me to access the database

1-  even if the password field was empty 
2 - if the id wasn't in the user table it self !! ( for example : 3 )

but if i enter an id that is exist it works well and i must enter the correct pass

this is my code :

index.php :

```
        <form action="login1.php" action ="get">
        user id <input type="text" name="uid">
        <br>
        password <input type="password" name="pass">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value ="login ">

        </form>
        <?php
        session_start();
        ?>
```

login1.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
   $uid=@$_GET['uid'];
   $pass = @$_GET['pass'];
   $link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die ('cannot connect');
   mysql_select_db('mydb');
   $query = "select upassword , id from user where id=".$uid;
   $result=  mysql_query($query) or die ('cannot run query');
   while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
       if  (($row{'upassword'} != $pass ))
       {
           echo " pass wrong ";
           mysql_free_result($result);
           mysql_close($link);
           exit();
       }
   }
   mysql_free_result($result);
   $query="select * from address ";
   $result=  mysql_query($query);
   while ($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
       echo "user : ".$row{'pname'}."<br>";
   }
   mysql_free_result($result);
   mysql_close($link);

    ?>
```

and here is my db :

```
  [DB][1]
```

Regards,,

Comment: this is my DB image : http://i.stack.imgur.com/XAhL1.jpg

Comment: Why not do the checking in MySQL (you should use mysqli)? `$query = 'SELECT id FROM user WHERE id="' . $uid . '" AND upassword="' . $pass . '"';` and if num_rows < 1 he is not logged in!

Comment: Arrays are accessed using square brackets like `$row['upassword']`, not curly braces. Also, this code is completely insecure. In addition to the traditional "dont use mysql_*" and sql injection issues, if a user id was passed in that returned no rows from the query, your while loop would loop exactly zero times, completely bypassing the password check.

Comment: Your code has virtually every major security flaw I can think of. You're using the obsolete `mysql_` functions; you're not hashing your passwords; you're not escaping your database query parameters... and those are just the major ones. Throw all of this code away immediately, and go to http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases and http://www.phptherightway.com/#security to learn how to do your DB queries properly and to avoid the kinds of security problems you've got in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, PHP array accesser is square bracket, not curly brackets.

Second, you code should assume password is wrong and disallow access to all by default, and only allow access if the password is right. For fail-safe reason.

For example,

```
$authenticated = false;
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   if  (($row['upassword'] == $pass )) {
     $authenticated = true;
     break;
   }
}

if(!$authenticated) {
  echo " pass wrong ";
  exit();
} else {

  ....[do you stuff here]....
}
```

Thrid, php mysql has been deprecated for a while. You should use mysqli or PDO instead.